# Call to a member function on non object in CodeIgniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate an username and check if this already exists in the system. Now the problem's that I've the user list in the table: `ea_user`
and the user settings in the table: `ea_user_settings`. Now:

```
ea_user > contain the id of the user that isn't remove from the system, the field 'data'

ea_user_settings > contain the username
```

So my function is this:

```
 public function validate_username($username, $user_id)
{
    $num_rows = $this->db->join('ea_user_settings', 'ea_user_settings.id = ea_user.id', 'inner')
                          ->get_where('ea_user_settings',
                              array('username' => $username, 'id_users <> ' => $user_id, 'ea_user.data' => 0))->num_rows();
    return ($num_rows > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

The problem's I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function validate_username($username, $user_id)
{
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('table_name');
    $this->db->join('ea_user_settings', 'ea_user_settings.id = ea_user.id', 'inner')
    $this->db->get_where('ea_user_settings', array('username' => $username, 'id_users <> ' => $user_id, 'ea_user.data' => 0));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array(); # add this

    $count = count($result);
        if (!empty($count)) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object, check my update with your code

Comment: what you get by this??'id_users <> ' => $user_id,

Comment: @Sandokan happy to help

Answer (score 0):

It isn't documented, but any of the `get()` functions (`get_where()` in your case) can return FALSE. (Learned this the hard way.) That would seem to be your problem. `FALSE->num_rows()` has no meaning as FALSE is not a object.

This usually happens because the query does not build correctly.
The compiled query can be examined by doing this.

```
public function validate_username($username, $user_id)
{
  $this->db->select(*)
       ->from('ea_user_settings')
       ->join('ea_user_settings', 'ea_user_settings.id = ea_user.id', 'inner')
       ->where(array('username' => $username, 'id_users <> ' => $user_id, 'ea_user.data' => 0));

 $compiled_select = $this->db->get_compiled_select(NULL, FALSE);
 //inspect or var_dump($compiled_select) to see what query statement was built.
```

After setting up all the join, where and other pieces of a query I have taken to checking the truthiness of `get()` before using its return. In your case something like this. Code picks up after (or instead of) the line `$compiled_select = $this->...`

```
  if($query = $this->db->get())
  {
      return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
  } 
  else 
  {
      throw new Exception("get call returned FALSE");
  }   
}
```

For me, the Exception is useful mostly during development. But you could put your call to the `validate_username()` in a try catch block if it would be useful.

Comment: Oh, and if `get()` is returning false try setting the optional third parameter to `where()`, as in and in your case,  `->where(array(...), NULL, FALSE);` I find that the problem is frequently incorrectly escaped values. The FALSE argument will stop Query Builder from escaping the inputs.